# Can't update label with a string upon clicking button

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter, label

Trying to get into Python, and I'm pretty sure the answer is right in front of me.  But I am not really sure how to implement other's ideas.

I have a list of books, each is a List with two translations of a title, desired inventory, and current inventory.  I want a window to pop up, then upon clicking a button, the window will display a summary of the inventory of the books. (There are currently 4 of them.)

I can get it to print the variable just fine but no clue what's up with getting a GUI message going.  Also, when I don't have invOutput defined in both places, I get errors... This doesn't seem right. If it is only Inside the function, it says it isn't defined, and if it is only outside I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'invOutput' referenced before assignment`

```
from Tkinter import *

#These are all the books sorted in lists.
books = [ #English Title, Spanish Title, Desired Stock, Current Stock
["Bible", "Biblia", 10, 5],
["Bible Teach", "Bible Teach", 10, 10],
["Song Book", "El Song Book", 10, 10],
["Daniel's Prophecy", "Spanish D Prof", 10, 10]
]

invOutput = ""

def inventoryButton():
        invOutput = ""
        for book in books:
                if book[2] > book[3]:
                    invOutput += "Title: " + book[0] + "\n"
                    invOutput += "You need to order more books.\n\n"
                else:
                    invOutput += "Title: " + book[0] + "\n"
                    invOutput += "Status: Inventory is sufficient.\n\n"
        print invOutput

##############

window = Tk()
window.title("Literature Inventory System")
window.geometry("500x500")

button = Button(window, text="Check Inventory", command=inventoryButton)
button.pack()

summary = Label(window, textvariable=invOutput)
summary.pack()

window.mainloop()


##############
```

Comment: If other people's code panics you and doesn't help, what good will any answer possibly do here? You have to learn to read code before you can learn to write code; there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to take what is being printed in the terminal and show it in the GUI right?  If so, this will do it:

```
from Tkinter import *


books = [
["Bible", "Biblia", 10, 5],
["Bible Teach", "Bible Teach", 10, 10],
["Song Book", "El Song Book", 10, 10],
["Daniel's Prophecy", "Spanish D Prof", 10, 10]
]

def inventoryButton():
    invOutput = ""
    for book in books:
        if book[2] > book[3]:
            invOutput += "Title: " + book[0] + "\n"
            invOutput += "You need to order more books.\n\n"
        else:
            invOutput += "Title: " + book[0] + "\n"
            invOutput += "Status: Inventory is sufficient.\n\n"
    #Set the text of the Label "summary"
    summary["text"] = invOutput

window = Tk()
window.title("Literature Inventory System")
window.geometry("500x500")

button = Button(window, text="Check Inventory", command=inventoryButton)
button.pack()

summary = Label(window)
summary.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

When you click "Check Inventory", everything that was being printed in the terminal is now shown in the GUI.

Comment: that was embarrassingly simple.